# Passing a dynamically allocated array from main to another function

Tags: c

First off, I have already looked at the example presented here:

[Passing dynamically allocated array as a parameter in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522396/passing-dynamically-allocated-array-as-a-parameter-in-c)

I am trying to pass a dynamically allocated array as a parameter to another function.

```
void InputIterations(int *iterations);
void CalcE(long double *E, int iterations);

int main()
{
     int iterations;  
     long double *E;

     InputIterations(&iterations);

     E = (long double *) malloc(iterations * sizeof(long double));

     CalcE(&E, iterations);
}

void InputIterations(int *iterations)
{
     printf("Enter a number of iterations: ");
     scanf("%d", iterations);
}

void CalcE(long double *E, int iterations)
{
     long double sum = 0;
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<iterations; i++)
     {
          sum = sum + /*formula for calculating irrational constant e*/
          *E = sum;
          E++;
     }
 }
```

However, when I compile my code I get the following error:

> `error: cannot convert ‘long double**’ to ‘long double*’ for argument
>    ‘1’ to ‘void CalcE(long double*, int)’ CalcE( &E, iterations );`

Does anyone knows why I am getting this error ?

If you could please explain my mistake or point me to a source that explains it I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Take a look at the error message again. It really tells you all you need to know. And if you still don't know, then go back to a book and read more about the address-of operator (`&`) and what it does. You need to do it anyway, because you really misuse it in more than one place (for example I suggest you take a closer look at that `scanf` call too).

Comment: You need to know that `Pi` is already a pointer and `&Pi` is a pointer to the pointer, a double poiner. So the call should be `CalcPi(Pi, iterations);`

Comment: **Choose a language.** In C++ the answer is simply, "use std::vector".

Comment: Okay, I chose a language for you by removing the C++ tag.

Comment: If you use malloc, you should look into free() too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
CalcE(&E, iterations);
```

you take address of E (of type `long double *`) and pass it as an argument to `CalcE`. `CalcE` accepts as first parameter a pointer to `long double`. But when you take an address of `E` you are given actually a pointer to pointer to `long double` (`long double**`), and that is not a pointer to `long double`. And this is what your error tells you:

> error: cannot convert ‘long double**’ to ‘long double*’ for argument
>      ‘1’ to ‘void CalcE(long double*, int)’ CalcE( &E, iterations );

So you should have:

```
CalcE(E, iterations);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CalcE(&E, iterations);
```

should be

```
CalcE(E, iterations);
```

Hope I helped

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you! Is it because E was already a pointer so I did not need to pass the address of the pointer?

Comment: @Corey Yes, in passing the address, you're trying to pass a double pointer where a pointer is expected, hence the error, `error: cannot convert ‘long double**’ to ‘long double*’ ` and also your program leaks memory because you never free the memory that `E` is pointing to.